# What is the Best Way to Extend Functionality?

Tags: java

I've run into a situation in which I was to extend the functionality of a given class, but I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. I started by invoking functionality "upwards" and have now switched to "downwards", but I see issues with both. Let me explain what I mean. First, the "upwards" approach:

```
public class ParentValidator
{
    public void validate() {
        // Some code
    }
}

public class ChildValidator extends ParentValidator
{
    @Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        // Some code
    }
}

public class GrandchildValidator extends ChildValidator
{
    @Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        // Some code
    }
}
```

This functions perfectly well, but it requires that I always remember to place super.validate() in my method body or the logic in the parent class(es) won't be executed. In addition, extension in this manner can be considered "unsafe" due to the fact that a child class could actually replace/modify the code defined in the parent class. This is what I call invoking methods "upwards" because I'm invoking methods from higher level classes as I go.

To counter these shortfalls, I decided to make ParentValidator.validate() final and have it invoke a different method. Here's what my code was modified to:

```
public class ParentValidator
{
    public final void validate() {
        // Some code

        subValidate();
    }

    protected void subValidate() {}
}

public class ChildValidator extends ParentValidator
{
    @Override
    public final void subValidate() {
        // Some code

        subSubValidate();
    }

    protected void subSubValidate() {}
}

public class GrandchildValidator extends ChildValidator
{
    @Override
    public void subSubBalidate() {
        // Some code

        subSubSubValidate();
    }

    protected void subSubSubValidate();
}
```

This is what I was referring to when I say that I'm calling downwards as each class invokes methods on classes "down" the inheritance chain.

Using this approach, I can be guaranteed that the logic in the parent class(es) will be executed, which I like. However, it doesn't scale well. The more layers of inheritance I have, the uglier it gets. At one level, I think this is very elegant. At two levels, it starts to look shoddy. At three or more, it's hideous.

In addition, just as I had to remember to invoke super.validate() as the first line of any of my children's validate methods, I now have to remember to invoke some "subValidate" method at the end of any of my parent's validate methods, so that didn't seem to get any better.

Is there a better way to do this type of extension that I haven't even touched on. Either of these approaches have some serious flaws and I'm wondering if there's a better design pattern I could be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what you describe as your first approach you are using simple inheritance, your second approach is closer to what the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) [GoF] called a [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Method_Pattern) because your parent class is using the so-called [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle): *"don't call us, we'll call you"*.

However, you could benefit from declaring the subvalidate() method as abstract in the parent class, and by this, make sure all subclasses are forced to implement it. Then it would be a true template method.

```
public abstract class ParentValidator
{
    public final void validate() {
        //some code
        subValidate();
    }
    protected abstract void subValidate() {}
}
```

Depending on what you are doing there are other patterns that could help you do this in a different manner. For instance, you could use a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to peform the validations, and by this favoring composition over inheritance, as suggested before, but a consequence is that you will need more validation classes.

```
public abstract class ParentValidator
    {
        private final ValidatorStrategy validator;

        protected ParentValidator(ValidatorStrategy validator){
           this.validator = validator;
        }

        public final void validate() {
            //some code
            this.validator.validate();
        }
    }
```

Then you can provide specific validation strategies for every type of Validator that you have.

If you want to get the best of both worlds you might considering implementing the solution as a [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_Pattern) where subclasses can extend the functionality of a parent class and still stick to a common interface.

```
public abstract class ValidatorDecorator implements Validator
        {
            private final Validator validator;

            protected ParentValidator(Validator validator){
               this.validator = validator;
            }

            public final void validate() {
                //some code
                super.validate(); //still forced to invoke super
                this.validator.validate();
            }
        }
```

All patterns have consequences and advantages and disadvantages that you must consider carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to 1) program against interfaces, and 2) opt for composition over inheritance. This is how **I** have done. Some people like it, some do not. It works.

```
// java pseudocode below, you'll need to work the wrinkles out

/**
 * Defines a rule or set of rules under which a instance of T
 * is deemed valid or invalid
 **/
public interface ValidationRule<T>
{
    /**
     * @return String describing invalidation condition, or null 
     * (indicating then that parameter t is valid */
     **/
    String apply(final T t);
}

/**
 * Utility class for enforcing a logical conjunction 
 * of zero or more validatoin rules on an object.
 **/
public final class ValidatorEvaluator
{
    /**
     * evaluates zero or more validation rules (as a logical
     * 'AND') on an instance of type T.
     **/
    static <T> String apply(final T t, ValidationRule<T> ... rules)
    {
       for(final ValidationRules<T> v : rules)
       {
          String msg = v.apply(t);
          if( msg != null )
          {
             return msg; // t is not valid
          }
       }
       return null;
    }
}

// arbitrary dummy class that we will test for
// i being a positive number greater than zero
public class MyFoo
{
   int i;
   public MyFoo(int n){ i = n; }
   ///
}

public class NonZeroValidatorRule implements ValidatorRule<MyFoo>
{
   public String apply(final MyFoo foo)
   {
      return foo.i == 0 ? "foo.i is zero!" : null;
   }
}

// test for being positive using NonZeroValidatorRule and an anonymous
// validator that tests for negatives

String msg = ValidatorEvaluator.apply( new MyFoo(1),
                                       new NonZeroValidatorRule(),
                                       new ValidatorRule<MyFoo>()
                                       {
                                         public String apply(final MyFoo foo)
                                         {
                                           return foo.i < 0 ? "foo.i is negative!" : null;
                                         }
                                       }
                                      );

if( msg == null )
{
   \\ yay!
   ...
}
else
{
   \\ nay...
   someLogThingie.log("error: myFoo now workie. reason=" + msg );
}
```

More complex, non-trivial evaluation rules can be implemented this way.

The key here is that you should not use inheritance unless there exists a is-a relationship. Do not use it just to recycle or encapsulate logic. If you still feel you need to use inheritance, then don't go overkill trying to make sure that every subclass executes the validation logic inherited from the superclass. Have implementations of each subclass do an explicit execution on super:

```
public class ParentValidator
{
    public void validate() { // notice that I removed the final you originally had
        // Some code
    }
}

pubic class ChildValidator extends ParentValidator
{
    @Override
    public void validate() {
        // Some code
        super.validate(); // explicit call to inherited validate
        // more validation code
    }
}
```

Keep things simple, and don't try to make it impossible or fool-proof. There is a difference between coding defensively (a good practice) and coding against *stupid* (a futile effort.) Simply lay out coding rules on how to subclass your validators. That is, put the onus on the implementors. If they cannot follow the guidelines, no amount of defensive coding will protect your system against their stupidity. Ergo, keep things clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to using composition over inheritance if your subSubSubValidate is related general functionality. You can extract new class and move it there than you can use it without inheritance in the other classes.

There is also

> "Favor 'object composition' over
>   'class inheritance'." (Gang of Four
>   1995:20)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a look at the visitor pattern may help you to develop your pattern.

Here are some information on it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: The only limitation of this approach is that you have to have a callback on the object being visited. If the object is "closed" you then have to resolve to reflection (ugly.)